# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "form". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag

Tags: angular, mean

I am making a form in angular application..there's no error when i compiled (ng serve), but in the browser there's no show (blank page)

Comment: I guess the error describes your problem clearly ..

Answer (score 0):

Put the code here,so that can be checked, moreover you are having an extra tag that needs to be removed